# Use count of repeating occurrences for replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find all repeating occurrences of some words in a text and replace each by count of occurrences.

E.g. for text

```
"Test1: ok ok ok ok ok fail fail ok"
```

I wish to get

```
"Test1: ok(5) fail(2) ok(1)"
```

I could write a simple prog, but maybe is there a simple way to do it by regex?

Comment: Regex is not the tool for that.

Comment: I do not believe that regex is equipped to solve this sort of problem on its own. I'd start writing that program if I were you.

Comment: Thanks to all. I've managed to write the program.

Answer (score 1):

Regex can not do what you want since it cannot count occurrences. But with the plugin `TextFX`, you can have access to many string operations.

The one that should be interesting for you is `word count`

[image]

To install the plugin:

- Go to `Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager`
- Select `TextFX Characters` and then click Install.

Comment: Thank you, Cyrbil. TextFX may be useful to me in the future though it is not the case this time.